# How do I customize a freehand circle with a fixed circumference?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I'm trying to plan a pen for my chickens in my garden. I have a total of 50 m of fence that I want to plot out on my Visio drawing.

What I want to do is having a freehand circle with a fixed circumference of 50 m that I can move and shape as I like. Much like putting a piece of string on a map and shaping it to see how it fits.

Comment: To clarify - do you want a shape with a fixed perimeter (in your case, 50 m) that you can move into any shape?